# Extra space with font change

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm trying to get a template cleaned up and I'm having issues with an extra pixel being added breaking the hover effects and header/footer overflow.

[Template link](http://sb.colbyfayock.com/tempp/)

As you can see when hover over any of the links, its shifted a pixel down.
Everything stylesheet wise is in em's to allow it to be responsive.
If I keep the font-size at 1em, everything works fine, but simply changing it to .75em like I have it there, it breaks it a bit.

[CSS Direct Link](http://sb.colbyfayock.com/tempp/style.css)

Update: Not sure if it's considered "hacky" but I put span's inside each of the link containers so that I could alter the font size without changing the line height of the link container. that seems to work fine

Comment: Hm, you're right. I was checking in FF, but just looked at IE and it has the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding or removing line height **line-height**.

For example:

```
<div style="line-height:30px;">Div content</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that on itself and its parents. Problem is I'm using line-height to vertically center the link inside the container.

Comment: @Colby try padding for vertically aligning then. add top-bottom padding (say 10 ) and reduce height by twice that(20 here)

Comment: Tried working that in, as I reduce the font the container doesnt stick to the top of the container so there's a gap up top as well... so I can't just shift it down. I'm going to keep playing with that though

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#header').css('width', $("#header").width());
    });
</script>
<li id="header"><a href="#">Header</a><li>
```

to always remain the same width

Comment: Hm :/ not sure the width is the issue here